# Dynamic style text color with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This code is in Angular

```html
<div [style.color]="'#' + prod.id.substring(0,6)">
  <small>{{ prod.id }}</small>
</div>
```

I need to write a similar code with vue.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [style attributes using an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)(key as CSS property and value as CSS value).

```
<div :style="{ color : '#' + prod.id.substring(0,6) }">
    <small>{{ prod.id }}</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

3 syntaxes you can use:

```html
<div :style="{ color: '#' + prod.id.substring(0,6)}">
  <small>{{ prod.id }}</small>
</div>
```

```html
<div :style="`color: #${prod.id.substring(0,6)}`">
  <small>{{ prod.id }}</small>
</div>
```

```html
<div :style="'color: #' + prod.id.substring(0,6)">
  <small>{{ prod.id }}</small>
</div>
```

**Note:** `:style` is equivalent to `v-bind:style`

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

---

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: { hex: '0f0' }
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <button :style="{ color: '#' + hex}">Button1</button>
  <button :style="`color: #${hex}`">Button2</button>
  <button :style="'color: #' + hex">Button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to do it using color code from a variable value

Comment: They're `hex` in my runnable demo, or `prod.id.substring(0,6)` in the sample.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get it, I'll try it

Comment: @Gharbi it's exact same as the accepted answer, just give some more options.